# If statement for excel

Tags: excel

I have the columns below and trying to get an if statement to put in another cell if #N/A is found in one cell and the other cell. I am getting this result

I am using this formula

=IF(AND(G16 ="#N/A", H16="#N/A"), "N/A", "Has Number")

the first column is G and second column is H the third is the result column

I am not sure why the third row is showing N/A as a result. I am wanting it to show Has Number if there is a number in the G column compare to the same row with the H column.if one of the columns has a number the other cell should say has number

we can even do it the other way if easier if both cells have #N/A then it is #N/A , else all the rest of combinations then "has number "

I am now sure how the third row is showing #N/A as a result . the result is in the third column.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use the ISNA function. Please try this.

```
=IF(AND(ISNA(G2),ISNA(H2)),"N/A","Has number")
```

Bear in mind that the result of any calculation with #N/A results in #N/A, like,

```
#N/A + 100 = #N/A
```

Comment: @matthew also note that returning the text `"N/A"` is different than returning an actual error with `NA()`.

Comment: yes. I wanted to just use another word so I can filter easier or compare later down the road.